# Finding the TCP throughput for intermediate switches along a transmission path

Tags: cisco, network-core, bandwidth, throughput

I am working on network simulation where my network should be as close from real-world conditions as possible. I am coding a function that calculates the latency and bandwidth of between `switch A` and `switch B` every minute. Isn't it more reasonable and accurate to capture the current TCP throughput instead of the bandwidth? Throughput formula as I remember is: `TCP window size/ RTT` but I don't know how to find TCP window size here (Assuming switch A and B are intermediate switches along a path from the sender to the receiver)?

Thank you so much in advance. Appreciate any response.

Comment: The bandwidth and latency between two connected switches isn't going to change. The two switches will connect to each other with a fixed bandwidth and latency. Also, switches know nothing about upper-layer protocols, such as TCP. There are things, e.g. IP SLA, to constantly monitor things like latency, jitter, etc. between two points on a network.

Comment: @RonMaupin I agree with you that bandwidth will not change. However, latency might change due to traffic conditions, is that right?

Comment: Not with switching, which will simply drop excessive traffic with wire-speed switching. Routing and queuing can introduce latency.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you. I just now learn that latency appears from L3 and above. This means Nodal delay, i.e. `Nodal delay = d_proc + d_queu+ d_tran + d_prog` , calculates type of delays appear from L3 and above, correct?

Comment: switches still have queues and absolutely do exercise varying performance based on traffic conditions and congestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several factors determine actual throughput, for example, datagram size (see [IMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Mix)) and datagram processing (fast switching, process switching, etc).  Terms such as packet per second, pps, and bits per second, bps, are distinct and are typically seen in performance literature.

Comment: "_fast switching, process switching, etc_" are routing terms, not for switches.

Comment: "Cisco routers and multilayer switches support the following three primary modes of packet switching: Process switching, Fast switching (route caching), Cisco Express Forwarding (topology-based switching)" - [Cisco Press](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2264831&seqNum=2)